# NodeJS Google OAuth2 Cookies

Tags: node.js, request, nodemailer

I'm ultiamtely trying to get a refresh_token to use in nodemailer, but am running into problems regarding cookies when attempting to sign in to authorize the app.

Upon request sending me to the Google login page, I can successfully login, however, upon logging in, Google complains that my browser has cookies disabled when clearly that doesn't seem to be the case. I have a feeling it has to do with my request call, but it seems correct to me.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

```
var request = require('request').defaults({jar: true});

router.get('/oauth', function(req, res){

    var gEndpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
    var gRedirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    var gResponseType = 'code';
    var gClientId = process.env.gmailClientId;
    var gScope = 'https://mail.google.com/';
    var gApprovalPrompt = 'force';
    var gAccessType = 'offline';

    var fullUrl = gEndpoint + '?' +
        'redirect_uri=' +  encodeURIComponent(gRedirectUri) + 
        '&response_type=' + encodeURIComponent(gResponseType) + 
        '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(gClientId) + 
        '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(gScope) + 
        '&approval_prompt=' + encodeURIComponent(gApprovalPrompt) + 
        '&gAccessType=' + encodeURIComponent(gAccessType)

    request(gEndpoint, function(){
        request.get({ url: fullUrl }, function(err, response, body){
            res.send(body);
        })
    })


})
```

[image]

Edit: Ended up going with using google's apis library which supports OAuth2. https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/

Still curious why this doesn't work though...

Comment: So, this is not a `nodemailer` question any more, right?

Comment: Not quite anymore. I entered the tag hoping that anyone else who was successfully got this working possibly could've run into the same problem and might have an answer.